# Unable to add users to Azure devops group "Contributors"

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to add a user from the UI to a team group. The search of the users takes a very long time. steps:

1. Open in the browser https://dev.azure.com/MyOrg/MyProject
2. Select "Project Settings"
3. Select "Teams"
4. Select "my Team"
5. in the members tab I select "Add"
6. Add an email (xxxxx@mydomain.it)
7. The search start searching for the email but doesn't end

I tried different browsers and different clients
I tried different organizzations.

I even tried creating a new organization, creating a new project and then tried to add a user in the Contributors group.

I noticed (using F12) I get an internal server error (500) when I have a post call to https://dev.azure.com/MyOrg/_apis/IdentityPicker/Identities

Any suggestion?

Comment: May I know how's the status of this? Do you has any puzzle or question on below explanation and work around? Just free to share your idea.

Comment: Our team has fixed this issue, and the deployment is in progress. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/936306/view.html Use this work around temporary, and it will be hotfixed on your org in 1-2 week.

Answer (score 0):

This seems be the issue which caused by our side.

---

As what you saw from **F12**, the request body it used is like below:

```
{
  "query": "{the fuzzy words you input, such as 'Merli'}",
  "identityTypes": [
    "group",
    "user"
  ],
  "operationScopes": [
    "msa"
  ],
  "options": {
    "MinResults": 5,
    ...
    ...
    ...
  ]
}
```

The cause which lead the error you faced is the value of `operationScopes`. It leads the backend class picking satisfied identity failed because of this invalid parameter.

---

The correct value of `operationScopes` should be `"ims","source"` here:

```
  "operationScopes": [
    "ims",
    "source"
  ],
```

**Error Reproduced:**

[image]

**Succeed to pick:**

[image]

This is the issue which relevant with the **identity picker** and should caused by ourside.

---

**Temporary Work around:**

So, since this issue is occurring on your working organization now, to avoid the affection that this issue caused, I'd suggest you input the **complete account** from UI, then **add**.

---

Also, in our official community, there has others faced the same issue with you. We will involve product group to do investigation and try to implement it. You can keep track on this [thread1](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/926534/cannot-add-user-to-team-due-to-server-error.html)/[thread2](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/928473/unable-to-add-user-to-team.html) to get latest update from our team.